# Server design for synchronous I/O services

Tags: multithreading, tcp, client-server

Im currently trying to decide on a design for a TCP server where the services that the server will provide consist of performing synchronous I/O (tons of DB queries - existing code!)

The system that this server will be part of has a couple of hundred clients that are typically all connected simultaniously and stay connected for several hours.

Basically all client requests are a result of human interaction, so the frequency is low but the response time should be as fast possible.

As I said, the service implementation must perform synchronous I/O, so a fully event based server is obviously out of the question.

Threads seem like a natural choice to serialize blocking IO, but you see advice to not use more threads than CPU cores.

Currently I'm leaning towards using a thread pool with a number of threads that is actually higher than the core count, since the threads will mostly be blocking anyway.

Would such a design be reasonable? What alternatives exist for a server with these requirements?

Comment: If the threads really do need to block, then you need as many threads as operations you might need to block on. But in most cases, not blocking is better. Creating lots of threads just to have them wait around causes all kinds of problems.

Comment: 'Creating lots of threads just to have them wait around causes all kinds of problems' - .NET managed threads, maybe.  200 unmanaged threads waiting around does not cause any problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems, (yes again, from ohter posts, not my direct experience), that 200 .NET managed threads 'causes all kinds of problems'.  200 unmanaged threads is not a big problem on Windows/Linux.

200 persistent database connections, however, seems like a lot!  You may wish to pool them, or use a threadpool for DB access with suitable inter-thread comms.